# macOS main menu sub items don't show

Tags: macos, storyboard, nsmenu

I'm using storyboard to create a macOS app.
[image]

For some reason, when running the app, the sub-menu item doesn't show up at all.

[image]

The item is enabled and hooked to the first responder just like the original demo items.

Comment: Did you drag one of the special menus?  The *Clear Menu* item makes me wonder if the menu started life as a Recent Items menu and perhaps the change didn't take.

Comment: That might be it, I'll let you know!

Comment: sbooth, a new menu from scratch solved it! Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you drag one of the special menus by mistake? The *Clear Menu* item makes me wonder if the menu started life as a *Recent Items* menu and perhaps the change didn't take.  You can tell by opening your storyboard as source code and checking for the *systemMenu* attribute on your *Scale* menu:

```
<menu key="submenu" title="Open Recent" systemMenu="recentDocuments" id="...">
```